# Clear variable in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to clear the value of a variable in python?

For example if I was implementing a binary tree:

```
class Node:
    self.left = somenode1
    self.right = somenode2
```

If I wanted to remove some node from the tree, I would need to set `self.left` to empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to delete created variables, functions, etc from the memory of the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545051/is-there-a-way-to-delete-created-variables-functions-etc-from-the-memory-of-th)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

What's wrong with `self.left = None`?

Comment: Not familiar with the None keyword. Is this similar to null in other languages?

Comment: Yes; it is equivalent to null.

Comment: @Bnicholas However it's not like `null` in PHP, in that setting a variable to `null` in PHP gives you similar behaviour in most cases as if you hadn't defined it in the first place. A value of `None` in Python is quite different from an undefined variable. `None` is quite like most other incarnations of `null`, however (until we get into more arcane details, at least).

Comment: It's not a keyword; it's a set-by-default name for a built-in object. You can do anything with `None` that you can do with any other "plain" object of unspecified type: store it in containers, print a string representation of it, check some metadata on it... Anyway, did you try Google for "python null equivalent"? I'm serious; it will take a bit of analysis, but the information is right there.

Comment: Open the python terminal and type `print x` and press enter. This will produce an interpreter error, as do most languages when you try to print an undefined variable.

But if you define the variable, and then try to clear it with None, using the `print x` code will produce the word `None` as output. I'm new to python so I could be mistaken, but this does not seem like the behavior of a cleared variable.

Comment: @Robino Me too. But I suppose that's the search engine's issue for misinterpreting my intent, not OP's or SO's.

Comment: Lol sometimes you just over think lot of things to make it complicated.

Comment: This solution isn't the best solution. It just assigns it as null, but it still is a variable. If you were to overwrite keywords - then you would still get errors trying to call a none type. Use `del variable`

Comment: @bnaul because it still takes up memory, it just doesn't have value, also, if you try accessing it, after setting it to None, it  doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 488):

The `del` keyword would do.

```
>>> a=1
>>> a
1
>>> del a
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But in this case I vote for `self.left = None`

Comment: sometimes this doesn't remove it entirely this only removes that reference to a in memory. This can leave ghost variables in memory that don't get gc.

Comment: `del` also has the disadvantage that if you try to delete a variable that doesn't exist it throws an exception, which is *usually* undesirable.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that if you accidentally declared a variable that is overwriting built in commands e.g., `type=… ` when you meant to type `type(…)` then deleting it is the easiest way to get back the original functionality. That is, if you keep it around as None you will still be cutting off access to the underlying function.

Comment: Jakob Bowyer --I don't know what gc means.

Comment: Garbage Collection/Collector/Collected

Comment: @JakobBowyer May I ask how you know this? Reading this makes me quite paranoid about how many other importances in programming are still unknown-unknowns to me

Comment: @hello_there_andy What do you want to know? This I learnt by looking into how languages work.

Comment: This was the one I was looking for. Playing at the cmd line, I had ... 
`set = set(myList)` and then realized I could not use set anymore as a function (doh). Using `del set` allowed me to use it again as a fx. Of course I'd never use that reserved var in an actual script.

Comment: To delete several variables, you can write:
```del var1, var2, var3```

Answer (score 132):

`var = None` "clears the value", setting the value of the variable to "null" like value of "None", however the pointer to the variable remains.

`del var` removes the definition for the variable totally.

In case you want to use the variable later, e.g. set a new value for it, i.e. retain the variable, `None` would be better.

Comment: What if I want to completely delete variable that in some circumstances does not exist. Is there any parameter to avoid an error? I need to delete several variables:

del a, b, c, d

I could use loop and try/except, but I prefer some switch to avoid it.

Answer (score 71):

Actually, that does not delete the variable/property. All it will do is set its value to `None`, therefore the variable will still take up space in memory. If you want to completely wipe all existence of the variable from memory, you can just type:

```
del self.left
```

Comment: I don't understand why the =None answer is so popular. This is the correct answer

Comment: The OP said `clear` not `remove`. del will kill the attribute and lookups. It is way cleaner to set it to None, than you can check `if self.left` and that would be good enough to check if a node is empty.

Comment: "It is way cleaner to set it to None" -- it's worth considering that if someone (yourself some time later or a collaborator) is reading the code `del`, IMHO, makes it more obvious that the variable can be forgotten about when 'mentally parsing' the code.

Comment: @NikolayGromov in your day to day code, when you want to get the value of self.left do you prefer to check `if self.left:`, or do you prefer to deal with a possible NameError exception that will crash your program if you don't handle it everywhere ?

Comment: Check `gcore $PID`, your variable still exists in memory.

Answer (score 50):

- If want to **totally delete it** use `del`:

  ```
  del your_variable
  ```
- Or otherwise, to **make the value `None`**:

  ```
  your_variable = None
  ```
- If it's a **mutable iterable** (lists, sets, dictionaries, etc, but not tuples because they're immutable), you can make it empty like:

  ```
  your_variable.clear()
  ```

Then `your_variable` will be empty

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to delete a variable, don't you?

ok, I think I've got a best alternative idea to [@bnaul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237659/4518341):

You can delete individual names with `del`:

```
del x
```

or you can remove them from the `globals()` object:

```
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]
```

This is just an example loop; it defensively only deletes names that do not start with an underscore, making a (not unreasoned) assumption that you only used names without an underscore at the start in your interpreter. You could use a hard-coded list of names to keep instead (whitelisting) if you really wanted to be thorough. There is no built-in function to do the clearing for you, other than just exit and restart the interpreter.

Modules you've imported (like `import os`) are going to remain imported because they are referenced by `sys.modules`; subsequent imports will reuse the already imported module object. You just won't have a reference to them in your current global namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Delete its contents by setting it to `None` and then `del` to remove its pointer from memory

```
variable = None; del variable
```