# Python: delete all variables except one for loops without contaminations

Tags: python, ipython

```
%reset
%reset -f
```

and

```
%reset_selective a
%reset_selective -f a
```

are usefull Python alternative to the Matlab command "clear all", in which "-f" means "force without asking for confirmation" and "_selective" could be used in conjunction with

```
who_ls
```

to selectively delete variables in workspace as clearly shown here https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html .

Now I am managing loops in which I am going to define a large number of variables, for example

```
for j in range(1000):
    a = crazy_function1()
    b = crazy_function2()
    ...
    m = crazy_function18()
    n = crazy_function19()
    ...
    z = crazy_functionN()
```

and at the end of each cycle I want to delete ALL variables EXCEPT the standard variables of the Python workspace and some of the variables I introduced (in this example only m and n). This would avoid contaminations and memory burdening hence it will make the code more efficient and safe.

I saw that "who_ls" result looks like a list, hence I thought at a loop that delete all variables that are not equal to m or n

```
for j in range(1000):
    a = crazy_function1()
    b = crazy_function2()
    ...
    m = crazy_function18()
    n = crazy_function19()
    ...
    z = crazy_functionN()
    if who_ls[j] != m or who_ls[j] != n:
         %reset_selective -f who_ls[j]
```

but it doesn't work as who_ls looks as a list but it doesn't work as a list. How would you modify the last lines of code?
Is there anything like

```
 %reset_selective -f, except variables(m, n)
```

?

Comment: Why not store the unnecessary ones into, say, a dict or a list? Then you can delete that all at once. And are you sure that it's more efficient if you delete those variables? MATLAB doesn't give that memory back to the OS, I believe, and I don't know how ipython's garbage collection works in the same scenario.

Comment: Storing all unnecessary variables in a dictionary is a good idea, I believe that the more the system is complex the less you have the control on it, at the end of the day, you can not have 100% control of what you are doing. For this reason I believe it is important to delete unnecessary variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to delete created variables, functions, etc from the memory of the interpreter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545051/is-there-a-way-to-delete-created-variables-functions-etc-from-the-memory-of-th)

Comment: If you want 100% control of memory management, you need to be using a language like C, not a garbage-collected, fully dynamic system like Python.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm not sure that's a good dupe target: OP specifically asks for features of `ipython`, but that's only marginally present in that post.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Just as jQuery questions can be answered with pure JavaScript, iPython questions about Python namespace management can be answered with pure Python. If this question is _only_ valid as a "what is an iPython magic function that does X" then I'm not convinced it's on topic.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if ipython's memory management is exactly the same as that of the interactive shell, then OK. But I'm pretty sure it's not (consider, for instance, the history and `Out[n]` references present in ipython). On-topicness is another issue, although I'm not convinced that an ipython-specific question is off-topic. Anyway, we don't have to agree:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak As quixotic as a quest to scrub Python's memory like that sounds to me, if OP really wants that (all references including `Out` removed), I will concede that's a terrible dupe target.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Frankly, I believe OP just "wants to be efficient" and feels that "deleting unnecessary variables" will help. Whatever that means, and whatever that actually does.

Answer (score 4):

The normal approach to limiting the scope of variables is to use them in a function.  When the function is done, its `locals` disappear.

```
In [71]: def foo():
    ...:     a=1
    ...:     b=2
    ...:     c=[1,2,3]
    ...:     d=np.arange(12)
    ...:     print(locals())
    ...:     del(a,b,c)
    ...:     print(locals())
    ...:     
In [72]: foo()
{'d': array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]), 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'d': array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])}
```

==================

`%who_ls` returns a list, and can be used on the RHS, as in

```
xx = %who_ls
```

and then that list can be iterated.  But note that this is a list of variable names, not the variables themselves.

```
for x in xx: 
    if len(x)==1:
        print(x)
        # del(x)  does not work
```

shows all names of length 1.

======================

A simple way to use `%reset_selective` is to give the temporary variables a distinctive name, such as a prefix that regex can easily find.  For example

```
In [198]: temp_a, temp_b, temp_c, x, y = 1,'one string',np.arange(10), 10, [1,23]
In [199]: who_ls
Out[199]: ['np', 'temp_a', 'temp_b', 'temp_c', 'x', 'y']
In [200]: %reset_selective -f temp 
In [201]: who_ls
Out[201]: ['np', 'x', 'y']
```

====================

Here's an example of doing this deletion from a list of names.  Keep in mind that there is a difference between the actual variable that we are trying to delete, and its name.

Make some variables, and list of names to delete

```
In [221]: temp_a, temp_b, temp_c, x, y = 1,'one string',np.arange(10), 10, [1,23]
In [222]: dellist=['temp_a', 'temp_c','x']
```

Get the shell, and the `user_ns`.  `who_ls` uses the keys from `self.shell.user_ns`.

```
In [223]: ip=get_ipython()
In [224]: user_ns=ip.user_ns

In [225]: %who_ls
Out[225]: ['dellist', 'i', 'ip', 'np', 'temp_a', 'temp_b', 'temp_c', 'user_ns', 'x', 'y']

In [226]: for i in dellist:
     ...:     del(user_ns[i])
     ...:     
In [227]: %who_ls
Out[227]: ['dellist', 'i', 'ip', 'np', 'temp_b', 'user_ns', 'y']
```

So we have to look up the names in the `user_ns` dictionary in order to delete them.  Note that this deletion code creates some variables, `dellist`, `i`, `ip`, `user_ns`.

==============

How many variables are you worried about?  How big are they?  Scalars, lists, numpy arrays.  A dozen or so scalars that can be named with letters  don't take up much memory.  And if there's any pattern in the generation of the variables, it may make more sense to collect them in a list or dictionary, rather than trying to give each a unique name.

In general it is better to use functions to limit the scope of variables, rather than use `del()` or `%reset`.  Occasionally if dealing with very large arrays, the kind that take a meg of memory and can create memory errors, I may use `del` or just `a=None` to remove them.  But ordinary variables don't need special attention (not even in an `ipython` session that hangs around for several days).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking help for the same task and I noticed the comment from hpaulj, about that %who_ls return a list of names then I remembered a little about metaprogrammin in R with the command eval(parser(text = text)), then I looked for and equivalent of the previous command in python to delete all the variables in lst_arch using the names of the variables ([R's eval(parse(text=text)) equivalent in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876540/rs-evalparsetext-text-equivalent-in-python))

```
    a = 1
    b = 1

    lst_arch = %who_ls
    lst_arch.append('lst_arch')
    lst_arch.append('x')

    for x in lst_arch:
        exec(f'del(' + x + ')')
```

If we want to filter certain variables from lst_arch, we can use regular expression or something like that to delete just those variables we want to delete.