# Is there a reset function in the Python console?

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

Is there a function that can be called from within the Python console that has the exact same effect as doing the following:

Calling

```py
   exit()
```

to exit the console, followed by calling

```
python
```

at the command prompt to re-enter a fresh python console.

NB: I am not seeking to just clear or de-clutter the screen, because using  **CTRL+L** accomplishes that quite easily.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545051/is-there-a-way-to-delete-created-variables-functions-etc-from-the-memory-of-th?rq=1?

Comment: @Sparky05      I think that ***is*** what I am looking for, although I'm not 100% sure since I am very new to all of this.  The question you directed me to does seem to give advice on how to go about cleaning out all the gunk accumulated during a session of messy learning in the shell. I see that if one is working in `IPython` or `Jupyter`, one can benefit by directly using a `%reset` or `reset` instruction. Thank you for the re-direction.

Comment: If you are new to python, I would highly recommend ether working in a Jupyter notebook or some IDE (choice depends on your use case). Jupiter notebooks have the functionality of restarting the kernel and executing all cells, which can be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the variables defined in the session then this should do your job.

```
import gc

del <variable_name>
gc.collect()
```