# Memory behaivor of Python

Tags: python, pointers, memory

I have a list which will get really big. So I will save the List on my HDD and continue with an empty list. My question is: when I do myList[] will the old data be deleted or will it remain somewhere on the Ram. I fear, that the pointer of myList will just point somewhere else and and the old data will not be toched.

```
myList = []
for i in range(bigNumber1)
    for k in range(bigNumber2)
        myList.append( bigData(i,k) )
    savemat("data"+str(i), "data":{myList})
    myList = []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to delete created variables, functions, etc from the memory of the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545051/is-there-a-way-to-delete-created-variables-functions-etc-from-the-memory-of-th)

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

In python and many other programming languages, object pointers that reference an unused object will be collected by the garbage collector, a feature that looks for these objects and clears them from memory. How this is done exactly under the hook, can be read about in more detail here:

https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/

Happy codings!

Answer (score 0):

Python uses Garbage Collection for memory management (read more [here](https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/)).

> The garbage collector attempts to reclaim memory which was allocated
> by the program, but is no longer referenced—also called garbage.

So your data will automatically be deleted. However, if you want to sure that the memory is free at a particular point, you can call the GC directly with

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

This is not recommended though.